# Exporting Quartz Composition to .mov file

Tags: quartz-graphics, quicktime, quartz-composer

I'd like to export my prepared quartz composition (I'm using Quartz Composer 4.6) to .mov.
I tried to it with "File > Export as a QuickTime Movie", but it asks me about duration time and after clicking OK it creates a file .mov what is "zero kilobytes".

I wonder it's a bug or I'm doing something wrong? How can I export it to .mov in another way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quartz Composer's built-in "Export" command takes the composition and wraps it in a special kind of QuickTime movie — in order to play this movie back, you need a Mac, you need QuickTime Player version 7, and you can't use any "unsafe" plugins (i.e., almost all 3rd-party plugins).  So, even when it works, it's of limited utility.

There are a few other options for taking the visual rendered output of a Quartz Composition and turning it into a normal movie (which you *can* share with non-Mac users) —

1. Use [qtzrendang](https://code.google.com/p/qtzrendang/) — it renders composition frames to a movie file.
2. Use [Kineme QuartzCrystal](http://kineme.net/QuartzCrystal) — it renders composition frames to a movie file, with additional features like antialiasing and motion blur. (*)
3. Put your composition inside a `Render In Image` patch, and feed the output to the [Movie Exporter Plugin](https://github.com/mirek/quartzcomposer-exporter).

(*) Disclosure: I'm one of the developers of this software.

Comment: I'm using a mac and the exported mov file is still not playable in QuickTime. By the way, it seems that the Kineme QuartzCrystal is marked not supported since Mountain Lion.

Comment: @Lenciel: You need QuickTime Player version 7 to play these movies back.  I updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @Lenciel: Kineme QuartzCrystal works on 10.8 and 10.9, even though it is not officially supported.

Comment: @smokris Thank you for answer. I didn't use any "unsafe" plugins in my composition and I obviously use the Mac. "qtzrendang" works, but the quality isn't the best. ``Render In Image`` with ``Movie Exporter`` gave the same effect like "Export as a QuickTime Movie". I use QT 10. So I would have to downgrade it.

Comment: @KonradKolasa: In that case I'd recommend trying Kineme QuartzCrystal.  (The free trial shows a checkerboard over the image; purchasing a license allows rendering without the checkerboard.)

Comment: @smokris Yup, this tool works awesome. It works even with mouse interaction when use ``Record Input``. I need to consider buying this.

Comment: @smokris trying out Kineme QuartzCrystal and it's successfully exporting into .mov but I can't seem to interact with the composition. I built a simple iPhone click animation but I can't seem to trigger the animation from inside Kineme QuartzCrystal. Any ideas? I tried Record Input but still didn't work. I'm on Mavericks and using Quartz Composer v4.6 with latest Origami. Thanks.

Comment: @Mac: Kineme QuartzCrystal records and plays back Quartz Composer events, which work with the built-in `Mouse` and `Interaction` patches (and any other patches that use Quartz Composer events).  But Origami's `Interaction 2` patch (and other patches derived from it, like `Scroll`) doesn't use Quartz Composer events, so Kineme QuartzCrystal has no way to record and play back Origami's patches.